# TortoiseHg locks up on SSH fetch from BitBucket

Tags: mercurial, ssh, bitbucket

TortoiseHg locks up when I do a pull from my repository on BitBucket using SSH.  It simply refuses to return, even after and hour.

I'm guessing that the problem has to do with the fact that my private key has an associated passphrase.  (Everything works fine when I do it from the command line, but I do have to enter my key's password).

So, my question is:  How do I get TortoiseHg to know my key password so I can do a pull using it?

Comment: Krtek has your answer (use ssh-agent!) but when debugging this sort of thing get tortoisehg to pass '-v -v' to ssh as an argument and check output to see on what it's waiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a **SSH-agent** that will store the deciphered key in memory.

This is really easy under unix, just launch `ssh-agent` and then `ssh-add` this will ask you for your password and then store the key.

For windows, you can follow this tutorial for using an ssh-agent with TortoiseSVN on windows : http://matttrent.com/articles/how-use-ssh-agent-windows-tortoisesvn . If you already have a key pair, only the part about Pageant is useful for you.